# CSS3 FlexBox transitions

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-transitions, flexbox

In this codepen example: http://codepen.io/DrYSG/pen/ovctn I created three flexboxes. The effect I want is that when one hovers over the middle box, it grows in size (color change in the demo is just to help me know about the hover).

In FireFox v19  this almost works correctly. But it is strange what it picks of the start and end widths of the animation.

In Chrome v25, I am getting rapid unstable oscillation of states (flashing). Really not correct.

In IE10 I get the same transition as FireFox, but no smooth transition.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do for FF or Opera, they have roughly the same behavior here.  I did try a `min-width: 400px` on the default state for the `.fixed`, but the resizing animation for leaving the hover state stopped functioning.  You were just missing some prefixes for Chrome:  http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/CBEnK.  I can't help you with IE.