# Can flexbox properties be transitioned, or animated in any version of Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, css-animations, flexbox

These [simple examples](http://dev.opera.com/static/articles/2013/animating-flexboxes/flexbox-transition-js/flexbox-transition-javascript.html) seem to work everywhere else. I've tried to adjust the properties within dev tools, but it just doesn't seem to want to animate these properties.

Furthermore, I can't seem to find any online documentation about this as a missing feature, or an issue. Has anyone else had any luck?

I just found this [comment on a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076657/css3-flexbox-transitions?rq=1#comment-31989435) which is a hack. I've further narrowed down the [example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jhbsr).